# Type error when reading properties of a function argument in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor

Here is the definition of the constructor function.

```
function Box (options) {
console.log(options);
this.x = options.x || 10;
this.y = options.y || 10;
this.width = options.width || 100;
this.height = options.height || 100;
this.color = options.color || '#000';
}
```

This throws a Typeerror stating it cannot read property of undefined at this.x = options.x || 10;

I am trying to create an array of Box objects. Here's the code.

```
for(var i=0; i<100; i++){
boxes[i] = new Box({
    x: 10+i,
    y: 10+i,
    width: 2*i,
    height: 3*i,
    color: randomColor(0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255, .5)
});
}
```

Am I missing something here. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: runs fine here http://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/n52mftw2/

Comment: @ itsyogesh: The code you've quoted won't have the error you've quoted. You *would* get that error if you just did `new Box()` without passing in an object (because within `Box`, `options` would be `undefined`), but that's not what you show above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you so much. I did declare a Box object without the arguments. Working fine now.

Comment: @Quince Yup works fine now.

Comment: could always add an `options = options || {}` to the first line to make sure options is there when you try to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've quoted won't have the error you've quoted. You *would* get that error, though, if you called `new Box()` without passing anything in (because within `Box`, `options` would be `undefined`). From the comments, it sounds like that's what happened. You can defend against it using `||` again, at the top:

```
function Box (options) {
    console.log(options);
    options = options || {}; // <== here
    this.x = options.x || 10;
    this.y = options.y || 10;
    this.width = options.width || 100;
    this.height = options.height || 100;
    this.color = options.color || '#000';
}
```

---

Side note: Using `||` to default things is sometimes error-prone. For instance, in your `Box` function, what if I do this?

```
var b = new Box({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    color = "#888"
});
console.log(b.x); // 10 -- huh?!
```

`b.x` should be `0`, not `10`. That happens because `||` works like this: It evaluates its left-hand operand and, if that value is "truthy," results in that value; if the value is "falsey," though, it evaluates and the right-hand operand instead and uses that as its result. The falsey values include `0` (they're: `0`, `""`, `undefined`, `null`, `NaN`, and of course, `false`), but `0` seems like it could easily be a valid value for `x`.

For those kinds of situations, you might use `hasOwnProperty` or `in`:

```
function Box (options) {
    console.log(options);
    options = options || {};
    this.x = options.hasOwnProperty("x") ? options.x : 10;
    this.y = options.hasOwnProperty("y") ? options.y : 10;
    this.width = options.width || 100;    // Maybe here too, if you want to allow 0 as a width
    this.height = options.height || 100;  // Maybe here too, if you want to allow 0 as a height
    this.color = options.color || '#000';
}
```

you can also use `in`, although it's slower on most JavaScript engines because it checks the prototype chain:

```
function Box (options) {
    console.log(options);
    options = options || {};
    this.x = "x" in options ? options.x : 10;
    this.y = "y" in options ? options.y : 10;
    this.width = options.width || 100;    // Maybe here too, if you want to allow 0 as a width
    this.height = options.height || 100;  // Maybe here too, if you want to allow 0 as a height
    this.color = options.color || '#000';
}
```